# PhoneGap camera / photo to server upload, failing, with random dialog appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am using phonegap 3.0.0

And in the process of attempting to upload a file to the server I am getting a couple things that are unexpected. First thing, a script error:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' line 624 of phonegap.js

(which I think is a lot older version of the js to begin with, as I could only find one on github)

Next thing I am getting which I don't see why/how this would prompt when I have never seen it on other apps.. is a little alert dialog:

[image]

When I click OK on the dialog thats when it attempts to carry out the rest of the script, and gives me the above error.

and the script I am using to upload is based almost to the letter the same as the one found on the phonegap site.. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

```
$('#select_photo').on('click', function()
{
    $('#choice_of_file').click();
});
$('#upload_photo').on('click', function()
{
    if(fmr.nullCheck($('#choice_of_file').val()) == true)
    {
        alert('Please Choose a Photo');
    }
    else
    {
        uploadPhoto($('#choice_of_file').val());
    }
});

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
(function(){document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);})();

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        {
            quality         : 50,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    );
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(domainURL+'upload/wizard/'+MembId), win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

the HTML for the form its reading..

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:-2000px;left:-2000px;background-color:#FFF;z-index:0" id="hide_file_input">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_profile_image" action="#none" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="choice_of_file" name="choice_of_file">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filekey should be the name attribute of file field

```
options.fileKey="choice_of_file";
```

Also it will be better if you can call deviceready before all functions are executed and put navigator.camera.getPicture in the onclick event of file field

Comment: Overall I was/am trying to follow the example. Thats the script they provide in the doc but has little context. The aim was to get that working to see how it works before pushing off and customizing, but thats not to say I wont give this a chance either ;-)

Comment: unfortunately thought.. this made no difference for me. the same error and dialog prompt. When clicking through my upload button. I can select the image or take one.. but after that.. when submitting the form through the app the error and dialog then fail..